# powershell import-csv mangles diacritical characters

Tags: windows, powershell, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to create users in AD (2003 server R2) from a CSVfile using PowerShell (v2)

when I use import-csv the resulting data gets mangled when names have diacritical characters in them.
Jerónimo ends up as Jer?nimo. Daniëlle ends up as Dani?lle etc.

If I output the file in de PS console using Type or get-content all is well:
PS> type .\Users.csv
PS> get-content .\Users.csv
The above commands result in the characters being displayed correctly so I'm pretty sure it is not it is not a consoleissue.

Does anyone have a solution to this or can explain this behaviour?

Regards,
Peter Berkhout

Comment: The problem seems to be in the handling of ascii/unicode. a2u.bat solved the problem for me.   http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batexamples.php?fc=A#A2U

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-Encoding` parameter of `Import-Csv`:

```
Import-Csv -Encoding UTF7 -Path Users.csv
```